# Regex, end of string must contain number

Tags: javascript, regex

I just need a really simple javascript regex test to make sure the last character of a given string is a number 0-9. I keep finding different variations of this in my searches but none that really match the simplicity of what I need. So for instance

```
var strOne = "blahblahblahblah"; // === false
var strTwo = "blahblahblahblah///"; // === false
var strThree = "blahblahblahblah123"; // === true
```

Any help is appreciated... I'm still trying to wrap my head around the rules of regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\d$` should do it.

- `\d` - digit character class
- `$` - must match end of string

Tests:

```
/\d$/.test('blahblahblahblah'); // false
/\d$/.test('blahblahblahblah///'); // false
/\d$/.test('blahblahblahblah123'); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex `/\d$/`

```
var strOne = "blahblahblahblah";
var strTwo = "blahblahblahblah///";
var strThree = "blahblahblahblah123"; 

var regex = /\d$/;

console.log(regex.test(strOne)); // false
console.log(regex.test(strTwo)); // false
console.log(regex.test(strThree)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex is pretty safe, give this a go: `/\d+(\.\d+)?$/`